# Model a fork relationship within ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

What does the ActiveRecord::Migration and ActiveRecord::Base look like for a class that references itself. I'm modeling an object that "forks" off an existing record and stores that relation in a :source field. That :source field will contain the primary_key :id of it's parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't include a "predefined" relation of this type, but you can define it yourself using the `has_many` and `belongs_to` helpers. You would need to add a foreign key, e.g. `my_parent_id` to the model (I'll call it `Thing`):

```
rails g migration AddMyParentIdToThings my_parent:references
```

Then you would need to define the relation specifying the foreign key and class names:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_thing, class_name: "Thing", foreign_key: :my_parent_id
  has_many :child_things, class_name: "Thing", foreign_key: :my_parent_id
end
```

You can omit the `:foreign_key` option on the `belongs_to` (*not* the `has_many`) if the foreign key matches the relation name with an appended `"_id"` e.g.:

```
belongs_to :my_parent, class_name: "Thing"
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do something like that I like to think of it as a model that links to itself.

In your migration file you just would add `parent_id` as as **integer** to that table/model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :parent, :class_name => "Category",  :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Category",  :foreign_key => :parent_id
end
```

Comment: You might want to change `has_many :child` to `has_many :children`.